# ¿Cómo escapar el carácter $ en HIVEQL?

Tags: hive

Quiero hacer esto:

```
insert into TABLA_1
select 'Valor $50' from dual;
```

Sin embargo me retorna error y me dice que el carácter $ debe ser escapado.

He intentado:

```
select 'Valor \\$50' from dual;
select "Valor \\$50" from dual;
select concat('Valor ', '$', '50') from dual;
```

sin éxito.

¿Alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Con acentos graves (`` ` ``) en vez de comillas simples.

```
select `Plan Equipo $50` from dual;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. No funciona con acentos graves. Da error de sintaxis la query.

Comment: Curiosamente en el entorno de producción la query funciona sin escapar el carácter $.
La diferencia entre los dos entornos:
Producción
=========
Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37)
Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37
Desarrollo
========
Apache Hive (version 1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169)
Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169)
Beeline version 1.2.1000.2.4.0.0-169

NO existe mucha diferencia entre las dos versiones, lo que me hace pensar en algún parámetro de configuración dle Cluster.
¿Alguien tiene idea de qué parámetro puede ser?